# Redeclared Section formatting - Centering

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, koma-script

I would be grateful if someone could explain how the following could be centered instead of indented? Perhaps a MWE is not required for this?

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
indent=1.25in,
    font=\fontsize{45}{40}\selectfont\mdseries\mathilde
    font=\fontsize{15}{10}
    ]{section}

\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{45}{40}\selectfont\fontspec{mathilde}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the alignment of all section levels redefining `\raggedsection`. Default is `\raggedright`. But if you want to center the section titles do not set an indentf for it.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\renewcommand*\raggedsection{\centering}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\fontsize{15}{10}\selectfont
]{section}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you can set a different alignment for chapters redefining `\raggedchapter`, that defaults to `\raggedsection`.

---

If only the sections should be centered you can redefine `\sectionlinesformat`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\fontsize{15}{10}\selectfont
]{section}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\centering\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Many thanks. Surprisingly, I tried the following: \setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{45}{40}\selectfont\fontspec{mathilde}} \centering which worked... I have no idea why at the moment and, do not have sufficient Latex skill to figure it out.

Comment: While it works, it is some kind ot misuse of the font setting commands. Maybe you want to use the section font somewhere else in your document. Then this text will also be centered.